# How to export a DLL from Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition C++ Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017, dllexport

I have a Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Started the new C++ console project. Marked the class I want exported as DLL with __declspec(dllexport).

But when I build my solution, I only get files with following extensions: .exe, .iobj, .ipdb and .pdb.

I tried searching through various settings in Visual Studiom including configuration manager, but I can't find where to enable the option to build the code as DLL. Is it maybe not a part of community edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select DLL in Configuration Properties of your project.

<sup>*Then probably figured out errors, if any*</sup>

---

[image]

Comment: Did this but still don't see any DLL's in neither Release or Debug folder when I build the project. @Threestarprogrammer57 is adding more info, has that got to do with it?

Comment: Check your output window, what its trying to generate and where

Comment: I did get it now.

Answer (score 1):

I have not VS community available right now, but IIRC, in the `General` project settings, you can select `Dynamic Library` as the `Configuration Type`

You may also want to set `Map Exports` and `Generate Map File` to `Yes` or something like that, in the linker `Debugging` settings.

You probably will also need a

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)     
{
    //you should keep hinstDll in a global variable

    //...

    return true;// true means "go on with loading the dll"
}
```